# The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Posisi

Tags: javascript, java, android

I'm trying to implement Google Map in android using Google API, but I am getting the error

The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Posisi

Here my Posisi.java :

```js
package com.ngohung.view;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Posisi extends Activity {
  static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
  private GoogleMap map;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.posisi);

    <<<< HERE THE PROBLEM getFragmentManager >>>>
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)) 
        .getMap();
    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
        .title("Hamburg"));
    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(KIEL)
        .title("Kiel")
        .snippet("Kiel is cool")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_list, menu);
    return true;
  }

}
```

Here my posisi.xml file :

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Posisi" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem...

Comment: What's your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: here mine : <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: If you're using Android Studio, your `build.gradle` file can override those manifest settings. What's it set at there?

Comment: Sorry, but i am using eclipse.. Any idea..??